# php error message in login form after error message has been set is not being shown

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, session-variables

I'm trying to create a simple login system, and right now I want to make it so when a user enters a username, and it doesn't match a session variable (not working with database atm), there should be an error message saying that the account doesn't exist.

I have used jQuery for client side form validation,and now I want to use ajax for executing a php script to check if the username exists (i.e., is equal to the session variable) without reloading the page.

Here is the code:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$error_msg = null;
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if (empty($_SESSION['uname'])) {
        $error_msg = "Error: account does not exist";
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['uname'] == $_POST['uname'] &&
        $_SESSION['pw'] == $_POST['pw']) {
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    else if ($_SESSION['uname'] != $_POST['uname']) {
        $error_msg = "Error: account does not exist";
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/form-validation.js"></script>
<head>
    <title> Login </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css">
</head>
</html>
<body>
<div class="center" id="login_win">
    <!-- htmlspecialchars converts special characters to html entities
         which ensures that hackers cannot inject damaging scripts
         into the $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] variable -->
    <form action="login_credentials.php"
          id="login_form"
          method="post"
          name="first_form">
        <h2>Login</h2>
        <?php if(isset($error_msg)) { ?>
            <p> <?php echo $error_msg ?> </p>
        <?php } ?>
        <label for="input_uname" id="uname_label">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="uname" id="input_uname"
               placeholder="Enter username">
        <br>
        <label for="input_pw" id="pw_label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="pw" id="input_pw"
               placeholder="Enter password">
        <br>
        <button type="submit"
                id="submit_btn"> Sign in </button>

        <div id="not_reg">Not registered?
            <a href="signup.php" id="not_reg">Sign up</a>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body {
    background-image: url("nature.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}

#login_form, #signup_form {
    font-family: Algerian, serif;
    color: #355f5f;
    font-size: large;
}

.center {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background-color: white;
    width: 400px;
    height: 325px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    border-radius: 25px;
}

#login_win, #signup_win {
    opacity: 85%;
}

form { margin-left: 30px; }
p { display: table-row; }

label {
    float: left;
}

input {
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: 30px;
}
#uname_label { margin-top: 3px; }
#input_username { margin-bottom: 20px; }

#pw_label { margin-top: 50px; }
#input_pw {
    margin-top: 47px;
    margin-right: 50px;
}

#input_uname-error,
#input_pw-error {
    color: crimson;
    font-family: Monospaced, serif;
    font-size: smaller;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#input_uname-error {
    margin-top: -55px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
#input_pw-error {
    margin-top: -55px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}

.center #login_form h2,
.center #signup_form h2 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

#input_email {
    margin-left: 50px;
}

#submit_btn {
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 165px;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#not_reg {
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 15px;
}
```

form-validation.js:

```
// Wait for the DOM to be ready
$(document).ready(function() {
    let data = {};
    $('#login_form').submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    })
    .validate({
        rules: {
            uname:
                { minlength: 3, required: true },
            pw:
                { required: true, minlength: 5 } },
        messages: {
            uname: { required: "Please provide a username", },
            pw: { required: "Please provide a password", },
        },
        /* submit to action page when
        *  the form is valid */
        submitHandler: function() {
            let login_form = document.getElementById('login_form');
            let form_data = new FormData(login_form);
            let data_arr = [];
            for (const [key, value] of form_data.entries()) {
                data_arr[key] = value;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login.php",
                data: { uname : data_arr['uname'], pw : data_arr['pw'] }
            })
                .done(function(msg) {
                   alert(msg);
                });
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see above, in the login.php file I try to first initialize the error message variable, then once the form data is sent back the error message is also assigned a string text, upon which I want the if statement in the form to return true and thus the error message should be printed in the form.
So my question is, why doesn't it print, or why doesn't the error message show up in my form? The if statement should be true at that point. What have I missed? Thank you in advance.

I have tried putting the php verification code in different files. I have verified that all the if statements are true until the one that is supposed to print the error message. I was expecting the code to execute the if statement again once the error message variable had been set.

Comment: For one thing, it's *pretty strange* to make an AJAX request to a resource/page that returns *an entire page UI* like that, rather than just returning JSON data.  Aside from that... In the response handler for the AJAX request all you have is this: `alert(msg);`  Is that alert working?  Does it contain the data you expect?  If the AJAX operation *itself* is successfully making the request and receiving the response, what you do with that response would happen right there.  If the AJAX operation is *not* working then you'd need to address that before you can do anything with the response.

Comment: FYI you can use `$("#login_form").serialize()` to get all the fields from the form, you don't need to use `FormData`.

Comment: Yes the alert and the message contains the data I expect, I have tested it with echoing the error message string. I don't however know how to use the response in the ajax function to make the error message show up in my form.

Comment: @Barmar I see, I will have to try that.

Comment: @David and yes I used to have ajax go to a different php file with just the php, not with the html if that's what you meant. But it also didn't work.

Comment: @Proxy: In that case your AJAX operation is working.  I *highly recommend* creating an entirely separate PHP file for handling that request and returning JSON data.  But whether you're using returned JSON or returned HTML, that's the spot in the code where you'd do something with that response.  It's currently "not printing" because there's no code to "print" it anywhere, only an alert.  You may want to take a look at jQuery's functionality for modifying elements on a page, like `.html()` or `.text()` or `.append()`, etc.

Comment: As David said, AJAX should normally send to a script that just returns data, not the full web page. So use something like `echo json_encode(['success' => false, 'msg' => $error_msg]);` and then parse the JSON in the AJAX code. Then it can do `$("#msg").text(response.msg);`

Comment: @David I see, yeah I will try to put it back in the separate file. I haven't tried returning it as JSON. So you're saying I can return the error message as a json or html object, and then put it in my form, all from the submitHandler method?

Comment: @Proxy: Correct.  Where you currently have the `alert(msg);`, that function is where you'd use the response to modify the page.  It sounds like you were expecting the entire page to re-load based on the response, and the whole point of AJAX is to *not* reload the page.  You explicitly control what to do with the response.

Comment: @Barmar Hmm okay, I'm not familiar with that syntax but I will try it.

Comment: @David Ah okay, that sounds exactly like what I need. Thank you guys I will try to fix this using your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the help of David and Barmar, I got it working.
I put the php code in its own file, and made sure to echo the error message.

I added a div to my html code:  `<div id="error_msg"></div>` where I wanted the error message to appear. Then, in the .ajax() method, I added the following code:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#error_msg").html(data);
}
```

Which takes the data (that which has been echoed) and turns it into html, (if I understand correctly), and then it is put inside the div, which in turn shows up in my form. :)